# Tabs highlight not working correctly - Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

When tabs are loaded, the current tab isn't highlighted in the tab bar. Only when clicking on the actual tab button does it highlight. Also, when pressing back from a tab that is selected to go to the previous tab, the highlight doesn't update to the previous tab's button.

When a tab is loaded programmatically then also the previously selected tab is highlighted.

Tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs #myTabs selectedIndex="0">
<ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" tabTitle="" tabIcon="md-apps" tabsHideOnSubPages="true"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="" tabIcon="md-calendar" tabsHideOnSubPages="true"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="" tabIcon="md-notifications" tabsHideOnSubPages="true"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="" tabIcon="md-menu" tabsHideOnSubPages="true"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

I found a GitHub link quoting similar issue, but the solution is not provided there - https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16524

**Expected Behavior**

*Highlight should work properly*